# achieve 3 images exact size CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

So I´m having trouble fitting 3 images in the same row ,[image: This is what I need..]

The thing is, that this images are not always the same so when I upload an image that its has a diferrent size everything moves., Any advise to achieve this ? thanks

HTML:

```
           <div class="first-slot">
             <div class="masonry-box post-media">
               <img src="upload/'.$row['fotos'].'" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                 <div class="shadoweffect">
                   <div class="shadow-desc">
                    <div class="blog-meta">
                     <span class="bg-orange"><a href="category-01.php" title="">'.$row['categoria'].'</a></span>
                      <h4><a href="single.php?id='.$row['id'].'" title="">'.$row['titulo'].'</a></h4>
                     <small><a href="single.php?id='.$row['id'].'" title="">'.$row['fecha'].'</a></small>
                     <small><a href="single.php?id='.$row['id'].'" title="">'.$row['autor'].'</a></small>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .first-slot {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    height: 35%;
}

.last-slot,
.second-slot {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    height: 28%;
}
```

Bootstrap

```
    .img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Use a CSS background image with `background-size: cover` instead. But, please, show the rendered HTML and CSS applied to the three pictures. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: why do you want to force 3 images on the same row? The purpose of bootstrap is for the UI to be fluid and wrap to adjust each users screen size. If they are on a small mobile phone it may look better to see the 3 images vertically in a column which is what bootstrap will do

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem. You can use these class names and css in you code. Change image src locations according to your requirements. And change `margin` attribute in css according to your need.
PS: dnt forget to include bootstrap link in your project file

```
 .imgItem{

        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .imgContainer{
        display: flex;
    }


<div class="row">
      <div class="col imgContainer" >
            <div class="col imgItem">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive 
                " alt="Responsive image" />
                </div>
           <div class="col imgItem">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive 
                " alt="Responsive image" />
           </div>
           <div class="col imgItem">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100" class="img-responsive 
                " alt="Responsive image" />
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```